# How do I make Vista machines see IIS on Win 7?

Tags: iis-7

I've got an ASP.NET application running under IIS on a Windows 7 Ultimate machine, on my home network.  However, no one can run anything against it in my home network; whether they're running another Windows 7 machine or Vista.  My guess is that I've got to share out wwwroot to everyone (Windows 7 and Vista), but I don't know how.  (Sharing on Windows 7 is, to me, the biggest mystery, and headache, I am having with this new OS.)

So, how do I do it?

Comment: Can the other computers resolve the machine name to an IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow port 80 through your firewall.

Go to Administrative Tools, Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, Inbound Rules.
Click New Rule... on the left.
Select local TCP port 80 and allow the connection

Comment: How do I allow port 80 through my firewall?  (Windows Firewall.)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better asked on Serverfault, but have you checked that all the machines in question are in the same domain (or workgroup if they are running Home editions )?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they're all using the same workgroup, but will double check.